# ng-repeat set a random color for each row

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, random

i'm trying to set a random background color from an array in each element in a ng-repeat. This is a simple fiddle i made:

http://jsfiddle.net/akbb6car/2/

As you can see, my problem is i can't set the color in each "row" but it's set in all rows the same. I can't understand how fix that. I also tried using an `id="$index"` but not works. Here's some code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dummy">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in customerData" class="col-sm-3">
        <div ng-init="getRandomColor()" class="contact-box" ng-style="{background: bgColor}">&nbsp; {{customer.name}} got: {{customer.color}}</div>
    </div>
</div>


angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.doc_classes_colors = [
             "#339E42",
             "#039BE5",
             "#EF6C00",
             "#A1887F",
             "#607D8B",
             "#039BE5",
             "#009688",
             "#536DFE",
             "#AB47BC",
             "#E53935",
             "#3F51B5"
        ];
        $scope.bgColor = "#339E42";
    $scope.getRandomColor = function () {
$scope.bgColor = $scope.doc_classes_colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.doc_classes_colors.length)];
    };

    $scope.customerData = [{
        name: "Mike"
    }, {
        name: "Tom"
    }, {
        name: "ASD"
    }, {
        name: "Lol"
    }];

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your color list is already in scope, why not just select a new color from it based on the $index?

```
<div class="contact-box" ng-style="{background: doc_classes_colors[$index % doc_classes_colors.length]}">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akbb6car/6/

I used `$index % doc_classes_colors.length` instead of just `$index` so that the colors repeat if you have more rows than colors.

If you're willing to bring in a dependency on *lodash*, there's a handy `_.shuffle` method to randomize the order of the list, which would make the order of the colors random on page load. The colors would repeat in the same order, but each page load would order the color list differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/akbb6car/8/

If you don't want to bring in lodash, I'd probably just look at their source to see how they do it, I'm not sure offhand.

Comment: Mmh, wait, your idea seems nice. but it's not really a random way. I mean, the first row will have always the first color in this way right?

Comment: Yes, that's true. And the order will always be the same. To solve these problems, you could shuffle the array randomly after initializing it if you want it to be random each page load.

Comment: can you show me how could i do it? i mean shuffle the array. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I lack the mathematical background to tell you how to properly randomize an array, but libraries like `lodash` can do it easily. I've provided an updated fiddle using the `lodash` `_.shuffle` method.

Comment: this is great, a really simple solution :)

Comment: oh, worth mentioning that _.shuffle may not work without lodash.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556010/referenceerror-is-not-defined